# How to remove users in Ubuntu that do not have a ssh key any longer?

Tags: server, ssh, cloud

I have a server in Google Cloud.  Within Google Cloud, I have several SSH Keys setup in the Meta-Data section. As a rule of thumb, I like to remove users SSH keys as they no longer work for us.  However, with that said, when I log into my Ubuntu server and run the command 'cat /etc/passwd' I still see the users listed there.  I have confirmed that in the meta-data section of Google Cloud they do not have a SSH key anymore.  Am I suppose to go in to Ubuntu and delete the users one by one from within the server as well?  If I need to go in and delete them from the server as well to ensure they cannot access the server then how do I do that?

Pardon my question if I have written it incorrectly as this is my first question I am posting.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `sudo deluser user` ... See [`man deluser`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/deluser.8.html)

Comment: Consult local policy for what should be done with old users' HOME directories, cronjobs, stuff that's used by other users,  ...

Comment: Thank you.. The deluser command is what I was looking for.  I apologize again, but I am trying to figure out how to mark this question answered successfully.